# How to send image from main page to another?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been searching for this answer for days and cannot come across an answer. Maybe because i do not understand them and can not apply them to what i am trying to do.

i am using php to save images on the server when the user presses submit and when that happens, i would like the image to appear on the next page in the image src. As you can see that the name of my next page is random but similar to my image name aside from the extensions. So i was wondering if that would play a part in helping me do something? as at the end of my php i go straight to the random stringed page that was created.

```
function findexts ($filename) { 
        $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
        $exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ; 
        $n = count($exts)-1; 
        $exts = $exts[$n]; 
        return $exts; 
    }

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);

        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 3000000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            } else {
                $ext = findexts ($_FILES['file']['name']) ;
                $newName = generateRandomString();
                $fileName=$newName.".".$ext;
                    while (is_file("upload/" . $fileName)){
                        $newName = generateRandomString();
                        $fileName=$newName.".".$ext;
                    }   
                $target = "upload/";
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                $target . $fileName);
                $newfile = fopen("img/" . $newName.".html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
                $newImgWeb = $newName.".html";
                copy("img/template.html","img/" . $newImgWeb);
                fclose($newfile);
                header("Location: img/$newImgWeb");

            }
        } else {
            //echo "Invalid File"
        }
    } else {

    }
```

this is my php and i don't know how i would go about doing it?
my html and php are seperate too, but are linked under the form action="upload_file.php"

```
<img src="../upload/<?php echo $fileName ?>">
```

but i'm just getting a bunch of errors, i have no clue on what i should do next. I'm just a beginner and learning a lot through doing this.

Also, i tried doing this in javascript where i would take the url of the current webpage, remove the begining url and leave with the end. So it would be like "adSEvF3A.html" then i removed the ".html" part and from there i couldn't identify which extensions to look for .png .jpg etc. so i couldn't do document.getElementById('image').src=newImg;

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the errors you got?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden):http://localhost/animerange/upload/%3Cbr%20/%3E%3Cb%3ENotice%3C/b%3E:%20%20…ange/img/template.html%3C/b%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E72%3C/b%3E%3Cbr%20/%3E & Notice: Undefined variable: fileName in C:\xampp\htdocs\animerange\img\template.html - and usually i don't even get errors but what i am trying to accomplish doesn't work

Comment: but i was wondering, can you obtain a variable from the  upload_file.php $fileName - so that in the image src i could write down the variable $fileName on it?

Comment: I would be tempted to create a file, Image.php, that takes a querystring parameter of the uploaded image.  The page would place the querystring value into the image tag.  Then you would just redirect the user to Location: img/Image.php?image=$newImgWeb

Comment: right now i chose to add a start_session(); $_SESSION['image'] = $fileName on the main PHP. on the html, i wrote <?php start_session(); $finalImage = $_SESSION['image']; ?> .. then wrote <img src="../upload/<?php echo $finalImage ?>" width="150" height="150"> but it comes with this on console: Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/animerange/upload/". note, that i wrote the session_start for both of them at the very top of the php code.image won't still wont appear. i even tried require and include for php.

Comment: CM Kanode, i did what you suggested and it worked like a charm! However, i was wondering if there was any other way to do this without showing the variable on the url? Much appreciated!

Comment: You can use a session variable instead.  There are probably other options.  Check the PHP online documentation for options.  Oh, I think that start_session() should be session_start().

Comment: @CMKanode so i managed to get it properly using include but now whenever i try to echo the variable $fileName it says it doesn't exist. Is it because the $fileName variable is far at the bottom of the php script? 'Undefined variable: fileName'

Comment: @CMKanode nevermind, i figured it out. It's because i didn't understand how the how the session_start(); and $_SESSION could be placed around the php. i thought they both have to be together. so, i would try and retrive a variable that has not even been created yet. so i thought, and searched again and again. Then i realised that session_start(); goes at the top of the php whilst $_SESSION can go anywhere within the php after the variable is declared so it can store the value within it. Thank you very much, this was buggin my mind a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had realised that i needed to put

```
session_start();
```

at the begining of the php file that i want to obtain the variable from. When i was working with session_start(); i had done it all wrong, and thought that $_SESSION had to always be declared right below session_start(); i know many of you will think it's stupid to think that. But hey, at least i figured it out.

test1.php

```
session_start();
$var = "hello.jpg";
$_SESSION['image'] = $var;
```

the variable that i wanted to declare needed to be above the $_SESSION so that it can be stored inside it.

index.html

```
<?php
include ('test1.php');
$image = $_SESSION['image'];
?>

<img src="upload/<?php echo $image ?>">
```

and then it worked.

Thanks CMKanode for helping me!